# Protected nested class not accessible to derived classes in other package

Tags: java

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish

File 1: ./net/Class1.java

```
package net;

public class Class1
{
    protected static class Nested
    {

    }
}
```

File 2: ./com/Class2.java

```
package com;

import net.Class1;

public class Class2 extends Class1
{
    Nested nested = new Nested();
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting

```
>javac ./net/Class1.java ./com/Class2.java
.\com\Class2.java:7: error: Nested() has protected access in Nested
        Nested nested = new Nested();
```

Is this error expected? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Problem

Few important facts (which many people forget or are not aware of):

1. *default* constructors (including ones for static and non-static nested classes) have *same visibility as visibility of class which they belong to*. So in case of `protected class Nested{...}` its default constructor is also `protected`.
2. element with `protected` visibility can be accessed only from class which

   - belongs to same package as class which declared that element,
   - extends (explicitly or implicitly) class which declared it.

Your `Class2 extends Class1` so it only have access to members of `Class1` (including access to `Nested` type). But since it

- doesn't extend `Nested` (even implicitly, it only inherits access to it since it is `protected`)
- doesn't belong to same package as `Nested`

it can't access `protected` elements from `Nested` class (including constructors).

#### Solution:

To solve that problem make `Nested` constructor `public` by either

- explicitly creating no-argument constructor of `Nested` class with `public` modifier:

  ```
  package net;

  public class Class1 {

      protected static class Nested {

          public Nested(){
        //^^^^^^
          }

      }

  }
  ```
- making `Nested` class `public` (its default constructor will also become public - see point 1.)

  ```
  package net;

  public class Class1 {

      public static class Nested {
    //^^^^^^
      }

  }
  ```